# Difference between Microservices and load balancer?

Tags: load-balancing, microservices

I'm fairly new to the realm of microservices but know basics about load balancing. I recently read an article about the microservices: [Enough with the microservices](https://aadrake.com/posts/2017-05-20-enough-with-the-microservices.html).

There it's mentioned that both the microservices and load balancers have clusters/different VM's for deploying many copies of application but in the case of microservices, we have a **separate database** in contrast to load balancers which backs a single database. Is it the only difference between them?

Here's the quoted text:

> "multiple copies of the same microservice can be deployed in order to
>   achieve a form of scalability. However, most companies that adopt
>   microservices too early will use the same storage subsystem (most
>   often a database) to back all of their microservices. What that means
>   is that you don’t really have horizontal scalability for your
>   application, only for your service. If this is the scalability method
>   you plan to use, why not just deploy more copies of your monolith
>   behind a load balancer? You’ll accomplish the same goal with less
>   complexity."

Comment: Read this.  https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html

Comment: I think a major difference is that microservices are splitting the load functionally, while load balancers are splitting it technically (i.e. with microservices you actually have a piece of the functionality served  by a node, while loadbalancers serve ALL functionality on multiple nodes) - how databases are used in each case is a result of this

Answer (score 3):

You can not compare Micro-services with load balancer... you should compare it with monolithic or SOA architecture.

In monolithic approach you mainly have only one database for the whole system and a monolithic application as a single project for your business.

monolithic is single unit But SOA is a coarse-grain approach and Microservice is fine-grain approach. In microservice architecture instead of designing a monolithic system you design different micro-services around your business capabilities and base on your domain and bounded-context.

each micro-services may have their own database. for e.g. order micro-service may have mysql database, recommendation micro-service may have Cassandra database and user-search micro service may have Elasticsearch or SOLR database.

In microservices each micro-service can talk to another base on two different communication style:

1. Sync (Rest is suggested)
2. Async (via message brokers like Kafka, RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ or NATS
   and etc.)

Scaling up-down in micro-services architecture is much easier than monolithic systems and you can even change a part of system and redeploy it independently without affecting the whole system.

Also micro-services adhere to let-it-crash paradigm and with using EIP patterns like Circuit-Breaker you can let user think system is always up and working and Base on CAP theorem you can have high-available system by compensating for consistency and having Eventual Consistency according to **BASE** instead of **ACID**

For load balancing Client-side Load Balancing with **Ribbon** devised by Netflix is very viable approach.

Also with using NginX, Docker Swarm and kubernetes you can implement load balancing.

In a nutshell there is nothing to do about comparing Microservices with Load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the (hopefully) simplest answer to your question:

- Microservices are a `different` (micro-) application each. Each with its own application logic and database.
- Load Balancers are usually used to distribute client requests to a cluster of instances of the `same` application.

That means: You can also use a load balancer to distribute requests for a microservice that is deployed in a cluster with many instances. But a load balancer can also be used to distribute requests to many instances of a large monolithic application (as opposed to micro).

The probably [best overview](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) for what Microservices are supposed to be.